# IE-9 Favicon Issue with IFRAME

Tags: html, iframe, tags, favicon

I am using <iframe> in my index.html page. But its replacing the original favicon of my index.html page with blank.

Unable to see the favicon for index.html

If am commenting the  tag its working fine in IE9.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
 <iframe src="http://somesite.com/"></iframe> <!-- Not Working Unable to see favicon -->

 <!-- <iframe src="http://somesite.com/"></iframe> -->    <!-- Working I can see favicon -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!!!

Comment: You could try using an absolute path in the link, just a `/` might work: `href="/favicon.ico"` or try `href="http://web.site/favicon.ico"`.

Comment: Matthew here the problem is when I am adding <iframe> its source is pointing to a different domain and picking that domain's favicon and replacing my original faviocon from index.html page.

Comment: When using <iframe src="http://sometimes.com" /> its getting 403 as response code and that replacing the favicon.

Comment: if am pointing to another URL like yahoo.com its working fine. Here the response code is 200

Comment: Why IE9 will replacing the favicon when its not getting the response code 200 in <iframe> src path.

Answer (score 1):

Found in IE if we are pointing to a URL in IFRAME and its response status is not 200 then It will replace the favicon.

so make sure you must have some valid response from iframe URL.